Is there a Python library that would solve a quadratic optimization problem?
I am trying to optimize a quadratic formula, where I have to simultaneously find a maximum wrt. $x$ and a minimum wrt. $y$.
More precisely, let
$F(x, y) = x M y + x 1^n$, where:
$x$ - is an n-dimensional vector of numbers, each $x_i \in [0, 1]$
$y$ - is an n-dimensional vector of numbers, each $y_i \in [0, 1]$
$M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of known coefficients (coefficients may be negative).
$1^n = (1, 1, 1, 1, ...., 1)$, so $x 1^n = (x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)$.
I need to find $\operatorname{argmax}_x(\operatorname{argmin}_y (F(x, y)))$
I am looking for a Python library that would solve the problem. I am aware that the problem can be converted to a linear-programming problem, and then there are libraries to tackle the LP problems.
Is there an open source Python library that would solve the optimization problem directly, without performing a conversion to the LP?

Now you've turned it into a bilevel programming problem.

Without prejudice as to whether your question has converged, it might be worth trying https://or.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009774/quadratic-program-qp-solver-that-only-depends-on-numpy-scipy is of use.


Expand $F(x, y)$ into a sum of terms:
$F(x, y) = (x_1 M_{11} + x_2 M_{21} + ... + x_n M_{n1}) y_1 + ... + (x_1 M_{1n} + x_2 M_{2n} + ... + x_n M_{nn})y_n + (x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n)$

Try to minimize the sum from the perspective of $y=(y_1, y_2, ... y_n)$. For each $y_i$, there is exactly one term in the sum involving $y_i$, we denote the term as $t_i$:
$t_i = (x_1 M_{1i} + x_2 M_{2i} + ... + x_n M_{ni}) y_i$

To minimize $F(x, y) =  t_1 + ... + t_n + (x_1 + ... + x_n)$,
each $t_i$ will have to be:
a) either $0$, by setting $y_i = 0$,
b) or maximally negative, by setting $y_i = 1$,
if $(x_i M_{1i} + ... + x_n M_{ni})$ is negative;

So to minimize $F(x, y)$ from the perspective of $y = (y_1, ... y_n)$, each $y_i$ will have to be either $0$ or $1$. Thus, the original problem $max_x (min_y (F(x, y)))$ can be reduced to finding the maximum for the following formula:
$(x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n) +$
$min(0, x_1 M_{11} + x_2 M_{21} + ... + x_n M_{n1}) + $
$... + $
$min(0, x_1 M_{1n} + x_2 M_{2n} + ... + x_n M_{nn})$



The reduced problem in (4) can be further reduced to the canonical LP problem. Introduce a variable $z_i$ for every term $t_i$, and set the following constraints:
$z_i \leq 0$
$z_i \leq (x_1 M_{1i} + x_2 M_{2i} + ... + x_n M_{ni})$
The goal is now to maximize $x_1 + x_2 ... + x_n + z_1 + ... + z_n$, subject to:

the new additional constraints for $z_i$
the original constraints $x_i \in [0, 1]$



To answer the original OP question, I am not aware of a Python library solving the initial optimization problem without reducing to the LP, but the reduction to the LP problem is straightforward.
Note that the original problem has $O(n)$ variables ($n$ variables $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ and $n$ variables $y_1, y_2, ... y_n$), whereas the reduced LP problem still has $O(n)$ variables ($x_1, ..., x_n, z_1, ... z_n$) and $O(n)$ constraints. So the size of the reduced LP problem does not increase asymptotically.

This problem can be solved using a LP solver because it secretly is a linear program.
For fixed $x$, the minimum $\min_y F(x,y)$ is obtained when the gradient vanishes. Note that the gradient of $F(x,y)$ with respect to $y$ is $x^TM$. Hence, the minimum is attained when $x^TM=0$ and $x\in \ker M \cap [0,1]^n$.
The next step is to calculate $\max_x F(x,y)$, assuming $x^T M = 0$. We conclude $$
\max_x (\min_y F(x,y)) = \max_{x\in \ker(M)\cap [0,1]^n} x^T 1_n .
$$ Hence, your problem is equivalent to the following linear program:
$$
\begin{split}
\max&\;\; x^T 1_n \\
\text{s.t. }& \; M^T x = 0\\
&\;\; x\in [0,1]^n.
\end{split}
$$

Thanks for an answer. Could you clarify a few things: a) Why is the minimum attained when the gradient vanishes? Note that for a fixed x, the F(x,y) becomes a linear function in y, and hence the gradient is constant, so how can the gradient vanish? b) The constraint $M^T x = 0$ for most cases will imply that x is a zero vector, but that will not necessarily be an optimal solution. c) The LP we're solving does not depend on y, i.e. trying to maximize $x^T  1_n$ without considering how $y$ interacts, isn't that intuitively incorrect?

a) The gradient of a smooth function (in this case, $F(x,y)$ where $x$ is fixed) at a global minimum is zero. As you said, $F(x,y)$ is linear in $y$ and its gradient vanishes if and only if it actually is the zero function. This is quite intuitive: If the linear function is not zero, then its minimum cannot exist. c) Yes, it does not depend on $y$. This is not unintuitive because your optimisation problem has the special form $\max_x (\min_y F(x,y))$ where $F$ is affine in both $x$ and $y$. I would say that nesting $\max$ with a $\min$ or vice versa would leads to simplications in general.

If the linear function is not zero, then its minimum cannot exist - the minimum can exist, when the variables are in the fixed range $[0, 1]$. I'm still not sure about the constraint that $M^T x$ has to be zero, what if $M$ has very small negative coefficients? Then $M^T x$ will be a vector of small negative values, and we could set $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ to 1, to get a large F(x, y) value due to the term $x 1^n = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n$. But thanks for the comments, you helped me to think further, and I generated my own answer below, you may take a look if you wish.
